# Loading a process to run a webrequest

Tags: php, c++, apache, cgi

When I was in my previous workplace which was a search engine company, I noted that they had executable files built using C++ , which were invoked with command line parameters by cgi script for serving each webrequest. (eg., when user hits a search button)

I could not understand the complete big picture, but was surprised that how much overhead would be there in launching a new process for each user request, since OS loader has to map the process space, etc. (it was unix solaris)

Is it an obsolete technology, or am I missing something ? (eg., if a process launching can be optimized by creating permanent mapping and they would have done that).  Or are there better alternatives to run C++ code for a webrequest?

Answer (score 0):

Solaris is probably well optimized for that usage. Yes, it has to initialize the process memory, but it can probably reuse a lot of the work and only a few kilobytes really need to be copied.

The only alternative to loading a process per request is to allow extensibility within the server process. This can affect stability, place restrictions on the server extension, and place additional demands on the programmer. The performance benefit might just not be worth it.

If the performance benefit is worth it, then you can rewrite the application as an extension/module/servlet/whatever.

Comment: You should probably mention [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com), which [is supported](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/node/5?q=node/10) in PHP.